# Can I name my daughter Riyah

Tags: names

We are planning on naming our daughter Riyah. I would like to know the meaning of this name and if it is OK to name her riyah. Also I read tat it has a meaning of 'victory' , 'strong'. Is that true?

Comment: That depends on the language, in Arabic Riyah basically is plural of Reeh and means wind/winds. Whether there's a connection to victory or strong must be checked, as both might have connections to wind in some expressions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> Narrated AbudDarda': The Prophet (ﷺ) said: On the Day of Resurrection
>   you will be called by your names and by your father's names, so give
>   yourselves good names.(Sunan Abi dawud)

As answered by brother the name means wind but I want to remark that our scholars have mentioned that those names should be avoidable which are not easy on tongue and eventually can be pronounced by some similar names with bad meanings suppose it is similar to Riya which means Showing off or Ostentation and when people would call that name in a flow some could skip the letter (ح) so keeping in mind now it depends on you to choose a name.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a unisex name. Riyah/Reyah **رياح** literally means wind or scent and it's used in the Qur'an:

> And it is He who sends **the winds** as good tidings before His mercy
>   until, when they have carried heavy rainclouds, We drive them to a
>   dead land and We send down rain therein and bring forth thereby [some]
>   of all the fruits. Thus will We bring forth the dead; perhaps you may
>   be reminded. [Al-A'raf 7:57]
>
> وهو الذي يرسل **الرياح** بشرا بين يدي رحمته حتى اذا اقلت سحابا ثقالا سقناه
>   لبلد ميت فانزلنا به الماء فاخرجنا به من كل الثمرات كذلك نخرج الموتى
>   لعلكم تذكرون

Comment: Oops, I reckon presenting the answer by giving a Quranic verse would be constructive for the questioner. Jazak Allah Khaira dear adam.